# Server returns error 500 on JPG GD image

Tags: php, gd

My webapp is ajaxing an image on server. If the image size is lower than  a defined value the script works as expected. If greater, the image is resized with GD. It works fine with PNG and GIF files but returns an Error 500 with JPG images.... Where am I wrong ?

```
            if (strtolower($e=='.jpg') || strtolower($e=='.jpeg')) {
                header('Content-type; image/jpeg');
                $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
                imagecopyresampled($gd, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
                imagejpeg($gd,$img_temp,100);
                }
            if (strtolower($e=='.png')) {                   
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($img);
                imagecopyresampled($gd, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
                imagepng($gd,$img_temp,9);
                }
            if (strtolower($e=='.gif')) {
                header('Content-type; image/gif');
                $gd = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($img);
                imagecopyresampled($gd, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
                imagegif($gd,$img_temp);
                }
```

Comment: Hum, despite the error 500 the JPG image is loaded and resized but I can't get the xhr.status==200 on ajax return to alert user... xhr.status is definitively 500. Any explanation?

Comment: Error 500 means "something went wrong", but it doesn't tell you what. But in general, if you get a 500 error, you should also get something more useful written to the server error logs, so try looking there to find out more info.

Comment: oh nooooooo I cant believe it :  'Content-type; image/jpeg' (with ; instead of : ) doesnt work with JPG but works with GIF.... reason why I spent 2 hours to solve the prob :-) I'm really sorry and ashamed

Comment: Hehe  :) Don't be ashamed, we've all been there. It's amazing how invisible these things become once you've been staring at them for a while.